# Android Intent won't pass value from Switch

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement

I have a Switch button, from which I want to pass different values (1 or 2) to next activity for calculations. But I always get 0. Any help?

```
 Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.edit_home);

     // set the switch to ON
     mySwitch.setChecked(true);
     // attach a listener to check for changes in state
     mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     boolean isChecked) {

     if (isChecked) {

     double input5 = 2;  
     Intent intentx=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
     intentx.putExtra("IFValue",input5);
             startActivity(intentx);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home field is important advantage",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } else {

     double input5 = 1;
     Intent intenty=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
     intenty.putExtra("IFValue",input5);
             startActivity(intentx);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     "Home field is not advantage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     }
     });
```

In next activity:

```
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     double input5 = bundle.getDouble("IFValue");
```

EDITED: I want to send values (input5) to the next activity, but if I add startActivity(intentx) inside of switch; then goes there imediately and not when I press next Button (buttonForward) as I want to.

Rest of the code:

```
    Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.edit_home);

     // set the switch to ON
     mySwitch.setChecked(true);
     // attach a listener to check for changes in state
     mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     boolean isChecked) {

     if (isChecked == true) {

     double input5 = 2;  
     Intent intentx=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
     intentx.putExtra("IFValue",input5);
     startActivity(intentx);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home field is important advantage",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } else {

     double input5 = 1;
     Intent intenty=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
     intenty.putExtra("IFValue",input5);
     startActivity(intenty);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     "Home field is not advantage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     }
     });



    Button buttonForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToMain2);
    buttonForward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    EditText edit_team = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_team);
    EditText edit_form = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_form);

    EditText edit_import = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_import);

    String ekipa1 = edit_team.getText().toString();

    final double input2 = Double.valueOf(qualityControl.getProgress());
    final double input3 = Double.valueOf(edit_form.getText().toString());
        final double input4 = Double.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating()); 

    final double input6 = Double.valueOf(edit_import.getText().toString());

    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Value",input2);
    intent.putExtra("Value1",input3);
    intent.putExtra("Value2",input4);

    intent.putExtra("Value4",input6);
    intent.putExtra("team1", ekipa1);
    startActivity(intent);








        }



    });
```

Comment: check your isChecked value i think it never change pls check it first from breakeposints

Comment: where is the startActivty(intent); function? how you started the next activity?

Comment: @BhanuSharma how could I fix it?

Comment: so is it your prob your cursur is going always in false condition dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a local instance of the `Intent` (intentx & intenty) inside the listener (I do not see you calling `startActivity()` inside the listener). The passed `Extras` only apply to the local copy not to the one you are using outside the listener with `startActivity()`.

**Update 1**

Character case matters when using `Extra` keys:

You are using `intentx.putExtra("IFvalue",input5);`

while in the next Activity you are using `double input5 = bundle.getDouble("IFValue");` which is a different key.

**Update 2**

> I want to send values (input5) to the next activity, but if I add
>   startActivity(intentx) inside of switch; then goes there imediately
>   and not when I press next Button (buttonForward) as I want to.

Then, you will need to have only one `Intent` instance in the whole `Activity` (define it before `onCreate()` and then do not start the `Activity` from the switch listener, but add the `Extra` for the single `Intent` instance:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class); // Class level variable
```

then change the following in the switch listener:

```
 // Intent intentx=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class); remove this
 intent.putExtra("IFValue",input5);
```

and in the buttonForward click listener:

```
//Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class); remove this
intent.putExtra("Value",input2);
intent.putExtra("Value1",input3);
intent.putExtra("Value2",input4);

intent.putExtra("Value4",input6);
intent.putExtra("team1", ekipa1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I think @Mohamed_AbdAllah it´s right. It seems that you are calling startActivity out of the switch scope.

Comment: True, I was calling startActivity out of the switch scope, so I added: 
startActivity(intentx); bellow the putExtra but it still delivers 0, not 2?

Comment: IFvalue is not IFValue as case matters (common mistake) :)

Comment: Corrected all mistakes, still not working. as Bhanu Sharma commented, it must be problem with isChecked value. How would I fix that?

Comment: if the problem was in isChecked, you would get 1 in the other Activity

Comment: I saw your edit now. If you want to start from the buttonForward onClick, then check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I get the one Intent logic now, but when I define it before OnCreate I get null pointer exception?